# Am I allowed to use my university's logo?

Tags: copyright, trademark

After graduating from college I am more than relieved to be done.

What I am curious about is if it is ok to feature the logo image from my school on social media or perhaps on my personal website legally?

I assume that I am not allowed but could probably get away with it, though I don't want to be doing anything that is technically illegal.

Answer (score 2):

Under Playboy Enterprises, Inc. v. Welles, it is likely legal due to fair use if you are only using the logo for identification purposes.  In Playboy Enterprises, Inc., the court ruled that the former Playmate of the Year was permitted to place the Playboy image on her website for self-identification even though she was advertising herself for commercial gain. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playboy_Enterprises,_Inc._v._Welles

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the trademark should qualify as Nominative Fair Use. Basically you can use the trademark to refer to the company.

Comment: @nomenagentis that's definitely the sticking point. However a court is going to weigh the facts. You went to this school and gave them money for four years. You are using their logo to indicate that you are a part of the tribe and you are not doing it for any commercial purpose. As I said, if they sued you it would be the first time in history that it's happened.